# Pandas - New column is a difference between 2 timestamps. How to convert this into hours?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Original data

```
Touch Time        Install Time
3/28/2019 14:06  3/28/2019 15:34
3/27/2019 19:23  3/28/2019 15:22
3/28/2019 15:01  3/28/2019 15:18
3/28/2019 12:41  3/28/2019 15:18
3/27/2019 12:10  3/28/2019 15:08
```

After this, I read the csv using read_csv and created a new column diff that's

```
df['diff'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Install Time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Touch Time'])
```

This creates a column diff:

```
      Touch Time     Install Time          diff
0   3/28/2019 14:06  3/28/2019 15:34    0 days 01:28:00
1   3/27/2019 19:23  3/28/2019 15:22    0 days 19:59:00
2   3/28/2019 15:01  3/28/2019 15:18    0 days 00:17:00
3   3/28/2019 12:41  3/28/2019 15:18    0 days 02:37:00
4   3/27/2019 12:10  3/28/2019 15:08    1 days 02:58:00
```

For my analysis, I want to convert the values in diff column into hours and then plot it using matplotlib.

I want the final data to look like:

```
0 days 01:28:00 should reflect as 1 

1 days 02:58:00 should reflect as 26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `total_seconds` then divide by 3600 to convert to hours.

```
df['diff_hours'] = df['diff'].dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be:

```
df['diff_hours']=df['diff']/np.timedelta64(1,'h')
```